# store value in variable in Redshift

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift

I am trying to store two variables in tw variables.

for example:

```
var1=$(select max(columnA) from table)
var2=$(select min(columnA) from table)
```

Can i combine the above statement and execute the same once and store max value in var1 and min value in var2 ?

I am using Redshift DB.

Answer (score 4):

I know this question is old but I too needed to find a solution to the question.  After much playing around here is the solution I came up with.

```
-- Create a temp table for storing the variables
create temp table tmp_vars (
  x int,
  y date
);

-- Store the values in the temp table
insert into tmp_vars (x, y) values
  ((select max(id) from table1), 
   (select max(date) from table2));  

-- Use the variable in a query
select *
from some_table
where date >= (select y from tmp_vars limit 1);

-- Drop the temp table
drop table tmp_vars;
```

Answer (score 1):

<s>Sadly AWS Redshift does not support variables or any kind of procedural features (PL/pgSQL) like triggers, stored procedures / functions, etc.</s>

Edit: Redshift added PL/pgSQL stored procedure support in 2019. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/bringing-your-stored-procedures-to-amazon-redshift/

Answer (score 1):

You can't define variables in Redshift.

But you could do the following:

```
WITH
  part1 as (select max(columnA) myMax from table),
  part2 as (select min(columnA) myMin from table)
SELECT part1.myMax, part2.myMin from part1, part2
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I am seeing this post in 2024.

So in 2024..`SELECT INTO` should work with your requirement.

Let's take an example. I have used [`current_date`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CURRENT_DATE_function.html) function here to get the current date, and [`date_part`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_DATE_PART_function.html) function to split it into segments.

Query: (Still no `into` here)

```
select
        date_part(year, current_date)::smallint as year,
        date_part(month, current_date)::smallint as month,
        date_part(day, current_date)::smallint as day;
```

Output:

| year | month | day |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2024 | 3 | 4 |

Now in a stored procedure, you can change this query to assign those values in to pre-declared variables:

SP:

```
select
        date_part(year, current_date)::smallint,
        date_part(month, current_date)::smallint,
        date_part(day, current_date)::smallint
into
        columnDate,
        columnYear,
        columnMonth;
```